# связать кнопку и div без id (js vanilla)

Tags: javascript

HTML

```
<div class="block__buttons">
  <button class="info__button">кнопка 1</button>
  <button class="info__button">кнопка 2</button>
  <button class="info__button">кнопка 3</button>
  <button class="info__button">кнопка 4</button>
  и еще 20 кнопок
</div>
<div class="block__info">
  <div class="info__block display-none">Информация о кнопке 1</div>
  <div class="info__block display-none">Информация о кнопке 2</div>
  <div class="info__block display-none">Информация о кнопке 3</div>
  <div class="info__block display-none">Информация о кнопке 4</div>
  и еще 20 текстов о других кнопках
</div>
```

логика: 
при клике на кнопку 1 нужно чтобы к div.info__block в котором информация о кнопке 1, убрался класс display-none. Эта логика должна быть реализована без использования id. И так далее кнопка 2 блок 2, кнопка 3 блок 3. 
Блоков и кнопок много, поэтому плодить одинаковый код через использование id не хочется

И я не понимаю как связать кнопку и блок без id?

Пожалуйста подскажите как подступиться к проблеме

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".block__buttons .info__button");
var blocks = document.querySelectorAll(".block__info .info__block");

buttons.forEach((btn, index) => {
  btn.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    blocks.forEach(bl => bl.classList.add("display-none"));
    blocks[index].classList.remove("display-none");
  });
});
```

```css
.display-none {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="block__buttons">
  <button class="info__button">кнопка 1</button>
  <button class="info__button">кнопка 2</button>
  <button class="info__button">кнопка 3</button>
  <button class="info__button">кнопка 4</button> и еще 20 кнопок
</div>
<div class="block__info">
  <div class="info__block display-none">Информация о кнопке 1</div>
  <div class="info__block display-none">Информация о кнопке 2</div>
  <div class="info__block display-none">Информация о кнопке 3</div>
  <div class="info__block display-none">Информация о кнопке 4</div>
  и еще 20 текстов о других кнопках
</div>
```

Comment: большое спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 0):

Ребята вот мой ответ на вопрос:

```
<div class="block__buttons">
   <button class="info__button" id="1">кнопка 1</button>
   <button class="info__button" id="1">кнопка 2</button>
   <button class="info__button" id="1">кнопка 3</button>
   <button class="info__button" id="1">кнопка 4</button>
    и еще 20 кнопок
 </div>
 <div class="block__info">
   <div class="info__block display-none" data-id="1">Информация о кнопке 1</div>
   <div class="info__block display-none" data-id="2">Информация о кнопке 2</div>
   <div class="info__block display-none" data-id="3">Информация о кнопке 3</div>
   <div class="info__block display-none" data-id="4">Информация о кнопке 4</div>
    и еще 20 текстов о других кнопках
 </div>




 const listOaeButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('info__button');
   function show(e) {
    let elem = e.target.id;
    let text = document.getElementsByClassName('info__block-hotel');
        for (let i=0; i < text.length; i++) {
               if (text[i].getAttribute('data-id') == elem) {
                    text[i].classList.remove('display-none');
                  }
                  else { text[i].classList.add('display-none')}
                  }
             }
                for (let i=0; listOaeButtons.length; i++) {
                    listOaeButtons[i].addEventListener('click', show, false);
                }
```